# Debugging issue with redirection in Wordpress

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

So I made a post, and on the admin panel when I edit, I am told I can preview the post with:

```
https://www.evil.com/promotions/halloween-mega-sale
```

However, it redirects to:

```
https://www.evil.com/promos
```

Under tools > redirection, I looked under Search target URL, Search URL, Search title, and I couldn't fine the rule that redirects to promos.

I see this rule, but it's not the redirection rule that's problematic:

```
/promotions/
/promotions/moving-sale
28 october 2021
```

Under log, I see:

```
/promotions > promotions/moving-sale
```

The question is what might be the other things that redirect users to different pages in Wordpress and what are all the different ways to debug what's happening in the redirection, so I can see what's the problem. The plugin for redirection we use don't see to be the cause of it.

Comment: Tools > Redirection isn't a default wordpress menu. Which SEO plugin are you using? That might be affecting the redirection.

Comment: You could install Rankmath and enable redirection debugging to see what's going on when a page is redirecting, this works for me.

Comment: How do you debug using Rankmath?

Comment: Using Redirection Version 5.1.3 By John Godley. I am not sure if I understood correctly though, what do you mean by SEO plugin?

Comment: A lot of people use SEO plugins to do redirects. If you're using this other Redirection plugin, that's the information that was needed. The menus you're referring to don't exist in default Wordpress, nor do the redirection rules you're referring to in the plugin menu. The issue is likely with your plugin. Have you tried disabling the plugin and seeing if the redirection still happens?

Comment: Ok, I just desactivated it and it still happens.